# Shrink an array of double elements (uniformly)

Tags: java, array, iteration

Is there a way to avoid the first loop in the method `shrink`? (`if` and `while`...)

The utility method `shrink` should reduce the elements of a double array by picking up elements from the original array "with a regular step respectively offset size"... but the first element should always be included, and the last element too, if possible.

```java
    public static double[] shrink(final double[] data, final int len) {
        if (data.length == 0 || len < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("data.length == 0 || len < 1");
        }
        double[] d = new double[len];
        double step = (double) data.length / len;
        if (len > 1) {
            int i = 1;
            while (Math.round(step * (len - 1)) < data.length - 1) {
                step = (double) (data.length + i) / len;
                i++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int j = (int) Math.round(i * step);
            d[i] = data[j];
        }
        return d;
    }

    public static void testShrink() {
        double[] data1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        for (int i = 1; i <= data1.length; i++) {
            double[] data = new double[i];
            System.arraycopy(data1, 0, data, 0, i);
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                double[] result = shrink(data, j);
                System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + Arrays.toString(result));
            }
        }
    }
```

The output of the method `testShrink` should look like the following:

```
1 1 [1.0]
2 1 [1.0]
2 2 [1.0, 2.0]
3 1 [1.0]
3 2 [1.0, 3.0]
3 3 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
4 1 [1.0]
4 2 [1.0, 4.0]
4 3 [1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
4 4 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
5 1 [1.0]
5 2 [1.0, 5.0]
5 3 [1.0, 3.0, 5.0]
5 4 [1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0]
5 5 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
6 1 [1.0]
6 2 [1.0, 6.0]
6 3 [1.0, 3.0, 6.0]
6 4 [1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0]
6 5 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0]
6 6 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

I think, it's also a mathematical-like question.

Comment: Your interface does not lend itself to a regular step, since you only ask for an output length. A good implementation would vary between two different steps in a dithered manner, or would interpolate.

Comment: What is the purpose and application of this function? Should it interpolate; i.e. should it take the average of two values when it "lands in the middle" between them?

Comment: (your current implementation with `round()` is basically the dithered one, with a non-uniform step; but could be improved)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Reinderien. The purpose of the method is to compress a stock market chart horizontally. Therefore, it is unimportant (for me) whether an average would be formed or whether the corresponding elements simply no longer occur.

Comment: @Reinderien the whole class is visible [here](https://github.com/tgrothe/Get-Average-From-Okx/blob/040267a6d986f73a8df950c64d4be66d96467e99/src/main/java/GetAverage.java).

Comment: Am I correct you want to: a) get a list of indexes in the original array based on the number of elements you want in the resulting array, and then b) use these indexes to create a new array consisting of the values at the indexes of the original array?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct, @RobAudenaerde ... I want a) and then b). Think, I could/should split the problem (or rather the method) into two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the first loop. It seems like a successive approximation calculation for the step size, but that shouldn't be necessary. Instead, we know that you have two defined endpoints of a linear function:

$$f(0) = 0$$
$$f(n-1) = m-1$$
$$i = f(j) = \frac {j(m-1)} {n-1}$$

That gives you your step size. It's easy enough to prevent divide-by-zero by having 1 as the minimum denominator; this also allows for `len=0` to act as expected (returning an empty array).

```
public static double[] shrink(double[] data, int len) {
    if (data.length < 1 || len < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("data.length < 1 || len < 0");

    double[] d = new double[len];
    double step = (data.length - 1.0d)/Integer.max(len - 1, 1);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
        int i = (int)Math.round(j * step);
        d[j] = data[i];
    }
    return d;
}
```

Note that since this doesn't use interpolation, it introduces [alias error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).

Comment: Thanks, I simply didn't have seen this: `double step = (double) (data.length - 1) / (len - 1);`.